# Why namespaces are rarely used in WordPress plugins?

Tags: plugins, php, themes, code, namespace

This is currently my impression. Many WordPress plugins I used do not use namespaces. On few occasions, on this website, I saw namespaces are good and should be used. Are there any drawbacks using namespaces?

The only thing I can tell PHP version must be at least 5.3.0. Other than that for some namespaces may be confusing. But I cannot think anything other.

Do you have any idea why there is such an avoidance using namespaces?

Comment: Actually the minimum version is 5.2, which IIRC doesn't support them, but namespaces aren't something people avoid, a lot are unaware they exist or how to use them, and some people use them prolifically, so you won't find a single concrete answer

Comment: I have learnt to use them recently while using PSR 4 and I used them on few plugins. The thing for me is autoloading a WordPress plugin is trickier and not easy when you can't get people to run composer on their own install (maybe I am wrong). Good one! You have to use namespaces for their countless advantages!

Comment: @SamuelElh, creating a basic autoloader is [fairly straightforward](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) - you can add one to your plugin or theme functions file pretty easily, then continue development from there. You don't need composer if all you're using it for is autoloading.